# Missing Edit button

Tags: editor

Recently I installed Wordpress 5.5 on my new pc. Installation process went flawless without a single error. However, after installation I cannot edit the pages since the little "Edit" button is missing, I tried a few different themes and tried to disable all plugins. Anything I can do?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your problem?

Comment: But you can still edit your pages and posts from the back end, right? Why do you need to use the front end 'Edit' button?

Comment: @Pixelsmith - because sometimes it's easier to find the page you want to edit from the front end, rather than slogging through all the page/post list. Having the edit button next to the post if you are logged in (and area allowed to edit) is quite convenient.

Comment: Reasoning totally makes sense, I just wanted to confirm you could edit pages, you just can't edit pages the way you normally do. 

The next place I'd check is the dev console, to see if the code is actually showing up when you're logged in and being hidden by CSS or whether it's just not in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The 'edit' button will appear next to the post title (or nearby) if you are logged in and have 'edit' capabilities. The placement of the button (or link) is dependent on the theme. Some themes don't display it next to the title. But you do have to be logged in to see it.

If you are logged in, you should also see the admin bar (black bar) at the top of every page. So, that's another way to edit a page/post from the front end. But you do have to be logged in, and your user has to have 'edit' capability.

So I would log into the back end (assuming you can and are allowed), and see if the black admin bar shows up. Then go to the front end (public side) of the site - in a different tab, if you wish - and see if the edit button/link appears. If not, then your theme doesn't show it - you will have to modify the theme (use a Child Theme, of course).

Comment: This was my first thought too, but we know they can log in because they turned off their plugins and switched themes, so it's probably not that.

Comment: Possibly, @Pixelsmith . Part of the answer is for anyone stumbling across this question; perhaps it will help them. But, more details needed from the OP.

Comment: I appreciate you help. In my opinion it is some sort of "page builder" plugin that is missing. Indeed I do have the "edit page" button on the top admin panel. But what I am looking for is being able to edit the pages straight and visually, like in Elementor but more simple. I was thinking it is a default wordpress feature but looks like it might be a plugin

Comment: it's definitely not something WP is providing out the box, the closest that WP provides is the site editor but that didn't exist when you wrote this question and certainly doesn't work the way you describe